# ASP.NET 4.0 publish a web application from VS2010

Tags: asp.net, deployment

I am not very familiar with publish feature.But here is the scenario
I have developed a web application in VS2010- I was under the impression that it will be the home page of the site.But the client now wants it deployed to a sub directory of existing web site.So I chose an FTPpublish to the sub directory from VS2010. The publish works well but problems arise when I try to access it using www.existing.site.com/Mydirectory/default.aspx

I then get the error that it cannot find site.master which is defined in default.aspx as

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="Schedule" %>
```

So I change the reference to Master as MasterPageFile="Site.Master" - this leads to error Class Site not found.

I am thinking I need to do some simple configuration change ???

Also what about web.config ? Should I deploy my web.config to the sub directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install a web application in:

1. root
2. virtual directory

So check that Mydirectory is defined as a virtual directory in IIS and configure the application pool for the right .Net Framework you used.

If you develop web app from 1.0 to 3.5sp1 .net framework you can configure IIS both with 2.0 or 4.0

If you develop your wep app for 4.0 framework you need IIS 7.0 or more and configure app pool for 4.0

So copy you web application in the sub directory folder:

- copy ALL bin folder
- copy all aspx, ascx
- copy web config.
- copy all static content

I suggest also you to take a look at MSDeploy